# Why doesn't UITextField tab to the next one when it has a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, virtual-keyboard, uiresponder

I have a UITableViewController whose cells contain UITextFields.  I've noticed some very strange behavior that is confusing and difficult to address.

When those UITextField objects are NOT managed by any UIViewControllers, using the Tab key on the software keyboard moves focus to the next UITextField.

But for whatever reason, when those UITextField objects ARE managed by a UIViewController (as in each one is managed by a UIViewController, one that doesn't override anything), then pressing the Tab key on the software keyboard only inputs a Tab character (\t) into the UITextField.

Why is this and how can I get over it?  I've read into how UIResponder works when it's a UIView, it effectively just returns the superview as the nextResponder.  In the case that a UIViewController is managing it, it returns the managing UIViewController, but UIViewController will just use its view's superview, so effectively they're doing the same thing.

Why doesn't Tabbing to the next one work?

Comment: What do you mean by "managed by a UIViewController"?

Comment: Meaning that the UITextField is created and held onto by a UIViewController.  As in if the each text view is not being held by a UIViewController's view property.